# Python: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I recently re-install Windows 10 and I have installed Python 2.7.13 (32-bit).

Also I installed dotnet 1.2.1 (32-bit) via pip.

When I tried to `import dotnet` I got the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dotnet\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import dotnet.moduleloader
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dotnet\moduleloader.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dotnet import PyDotnet as _dotnet
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any suggestions about that?

Comment: Just type import dotnet in your shell and hit enter. Make sure that you don't get an error. If you do get an error, then you need to install it again. Maybe you need to update pip first before using it to download dotnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was some missing DLL files for Windows. When I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) the error was gone.